# Achievements dialog reports incorrect data

Tags: feature-request, bug, achievements-dialog

On 30 July 2018, 21:09 UTC+2 I have posted [my first StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768515/how-to-do-static-linking-of-libwinpthread-1-dll-in-mingw/51602330#51602330). Exactly three months later, it has been upvoted, thus awarding me 10 Reputation, for a total of 11. Recently, it has been downvoted, and I lost 2 Reputation in the process. Due to that, my Reputation now equals 9.

Meanwhile, my achievements dialog claims that I've earned the "talk in chat", "vote up" and "flag posts" privileges, as shown here:
[image]

Because the privileges are actually awarded at 20, 15 and 15 Reputation, respectively, I believe that this discrepancy might be a result of the person who recently downvoted my answer upvoting it at first, then changing their mind. If that is the case, I would like to request that the achievements dialog either accounts for the results of such vote changes, or only gets updated once a vote cannot be cancelled anymore.

Comment: well an accept can be revoked at any time and an answer can be deleted so there's plenty of ways to lose rep besides cancelling an upvote.

Comment: See also, on the global Meta: [“We don't ‘revoke’ privilege gain messages by design.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224022/incorrectly-informed-of-gaining-a-privilege)

Comment: Well, that part of the design sure seems counterintuitive to me, hence I believe that the feature request is still a thing, but so be it, I suppose :-) Thank You.

Comment: Understandably so. Worse, you won't be notified again when you pass the threshold. You never get notified of the same achievement twice.